# extract number of A tags using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on an enterprise application where I can have either several links present in table or none depending on the data.

The links appear in the table and have following code behind them:

```
<td  class="Row">
  <span  id='s_3_2_14_0' >
    <a href='JavaScript:SWETargetGotoURL("/eservice_enu/start.swe?SWECmd=GotoView&SWEView=Active+PO+Serial+View&SWEPostnApplet=Purchase+Order+List+Applet&SWEPostnRowId=1-KPBLOZ","_self")'>2001103009</a>
  </span>
</td>
```

I need to find all the `<a>` tags present in the page inside `<span>` tag
having following text:

```
SWEView=Active+PO+Serial+View&SWEPostnApplet=Purchase+Order+List+Applet
```

I tried the following expression but it returns 0:

```
$('a[href*="SWEView=Active+PO+Serial+View&SWEPostnApplet=Purchase+Order+List+Applet"').length;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a ]

```
$('a[href*="SWEView=Active+PO+Serial+View&SWEPostnApplet=Purchase+Order+List+Applet"]').length;
```

Comment: ohh.. such a silly mistake. It started working after I added ]

Comment: @user1017268: NP. We all need a second pair of eyes sometimes!

Answer (score 2):

Missing **ending ]**     in your selector

```
$('a[href*="SWEView=Active+PO+Serial+View&SWEPostnApplet=Purchase+Order+List+Applet"]').length;
```

Comment: Just noticed that you beat me to the same answer...

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    $().ready(function() {
       $('span a[href*="SWEView=Active+PO+Serial+View&SWEPostnApplet=Purchase+Order+List+Applet"]').length;
       /* In order to check the count you can use an alert */       
       alert($('span a[href*="SWEView=Active+PO+Serial+View&SWEPostnApplet=Purchase+Order+List+Applet"]').length);
    });
```